# Zero an object in Golang Template

Tags: go, templates, prometheus

```
{{ define "default.message" }}
{{- if gt (len .Alerts.Firing) 0 -}}
{{- range $index, $alert := .Alerts.Firing -}}
{{- if eq $index 0 -}}
Detail: {{ $alert.Labels.alertname }}
# Here I'm going to zero $alert
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

hello, I want to zero `.Alerts.Firing`, which is also `$alert` after iteration over it.
I'm new to golang, Please help, thanks.

Supplement：
Actually it's a template of `Prometheus` alert. The orginal date is created  by `alertmanager` and send to `receiver`( wechat).
Here is wechat template

```
    {{ define "wechat.default.message" }}
    {{- if gt (len .Alerts.Firing) 0 -}}
    {{- range $index, $alert := .Alerts.Firing -}}
    {{- if eq $index 0 -}}
    Detail: {{ $alert.Labels.alertname }}
    {{- end }}
    ---- Problem started ------
    Message: {{ $alert.Annotations.description }}
    Time: {{ ($alert.StartsAt.Add 28800e9).Format "2006-01-02 15:04:05" }}
    {{ if gt (len $alert.Labels.instance) 0 }}ip: {{ $alert.Labels.instance }};{{- end }}
    {{- if gt (len $alert.Labels.namespace) 0 }}namespace: {{ $alert.Labels.namespace }};{{- end }}
    {{- if gt (len $alert.Labels.node) 0 }}Node: {{ $alert.Labels.node }};{{- end }}
    {{- if gt (len $alert.Labels.pod_name) 0 }}Pod: {{ $alert.Labels.pod_name }}{{- end }}
    -----------------
    {{ $alert :="" }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}

    {{- if gt (len .Alerts.Resolved) 0 -}}
    {{- range $index, $alert := .Alerts.Resolved -}}
    {{- if eq $index 0 }}

    !!!! Problem resolved !!!!!

    Detail: {{ $alert.Labels.alertname }}

    {{- end }}
    Started_at: {{ ($alert.StartsAt.Add 28800e9).Format "2006-01-02 15:04:05" }}
    Resolved_at: {{ ($alert.StartsAt.Add 28800e9).Format "2006-01-02 15:04:05" }}
    -------
    {{ if gt (len $alert.Labels.instance) 0 -}}ip: {{ $alert.Labels.instance }};{{- end }}
    {{- if gt (len $alert.Labels.namespace) 0 -}}namespace: {{ $alert.Labels.namespace }};{{- end }}
    {{- if gt (len $alert.Labels.node) 0 -}}Node: {{ $alert.Labels.node }};{{- end }}
    {{- if gt (len $alert.Labels.pod_name) 0 -}}Pod: {{ $alert.Labels.pod_name }}{{- end }}
    {{ $alert :="" }}
    -----------------
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
```

So it's hard to see the raw data sent by `alertmanager`. What I can see only it the result rendered by this template. Please see below.

```
################# The first  alert #########
##### As we can see 232.20 is in the state of 'resolved' ###

Detail: Node is down
---- Problem started ------
Message: Node is down
  VALUE = 0
  LABELS = 172.16.232.18:9100
Time: 2022-06-02 14:47:51
ip: 172.16.232.18:9100;
-----------------


!!!! Problem resolved !!!!!

Detail: Node is down
Started_at: 2022-06-02 14:47:21
Resolved_at: 2022-06-02 14:47:21
-------
ip: 172.16.232.20:9100;

-----------------

#####################  The second alert    #######
#######  232.20 is still in the state of resolved, it seems it's duplicated， that's why I'm going to zero it ####

!!!! Problem resolved !!!!!

Detail: Node is down
Started_at: 2022-06-02 14:47:51
Resolved_at: 2022-06-02 14:47:51
-------
ip: 172.16.232.18:9100;

-----------------
Started_at: 2022-06-02 14:47:21
Resolved_at: 2022-06-02 14:47:21
-------
ip: 172.16.232.20:9100;

-----------------
```

Supplyment:

1. raw data of first alert.

```
[FIRING:1] Node is down (powerdns prod node_exporter critical)
instance is down.
Alerts Firing:
Labels:
 - alertname = Node is down
 - app = powerdns
 - env = prod
 - instance = 172.16.232.18:9100
 - job = node_exporter
 - severity = critical
Annotations:
 - description = Node is down
  VALUE = 0
  LABELS = 172.16.232.18:9100
 - summary = instance is down.
Source: http://pt-prometheus-server-85944ccff6-qvtc4:9090/graph?g0.expr=up%7Bjob%3D%22node_exporter%22%7D+%3D%3D+0&g0.tab=1

Alerts Resolved:
Labels:
 - alertname = Node is down
 - app = powerdns
 - env = prod
 - instance = 172.16.232.20:9100
 - job = node_exporter
 - severity = critical
Annotations:
 - description = Node is down
  VALUE = 0
  LABELS = 172.16.232.20:9100
 - summary = instance is down.
Source: http://pt-prometheus-server-85944ccff6-qvtc4:9090/graph?g0.expr=up%7Bjob%3D%22node_exporter%22%7D+%3D%3D+0&g0.tab=1

AlertmanagerUrl:
http://alertmgr.pacific-textiles.com/#/alerts?receiver=wechat
```

and
2. raw data of second alert.

```
[RESOLVED] Node is down (powerdns prod node_exporter critical)
instance is down.

Alerts Resolved:
Labels:
 - alertname = Node is down
 - app = powerdns
 - env = prod
 - instance = 172.16.232.18:9100
 - job = node_exporter
 - severity = critical
Annotations:
 - description = Node is down
  VALUE = 0
  LABELS = 172.16.232.18:9100
 - summary = instance is down.
Source: http://pt-prometheus-server-85944ccff6-qvtc4:9090/graph?g0.expr=up%7Bjob%3D%22node_exporter%22%7D+%3D%3D+0&g0.tab=1
Labels:
 - alertname = Node is down
 - app = powerdns
 - env = prod
 - instance = 172.16.232.20:9100
 - job = node_exporter
 - severity = critical
Annotations:
 - description = Node is down
  VALUE = 0
  LABELS = 172.16.232.20:9100
 - summary = instance is down.
Source: http://pt-prometheus-server-85944ccff6-qvtc4:9090/graph?g0.expr=up%7Bjob%3D%22node_exporter%22%7D+%3D%3D+0&g0.tab=1

AlertmanagerUrl:
http://alertmgr.pacific-textiles.com/#/alerts?receiver=wechat
```

Comment: Why do you want to zero it? And what is the type of the value it holds? Just assign the zero value of its type to it if you must.

Comment: `$alert = ""` ？

Comment: If `$alert` would be a `string`, yes, but it's most certainly not as you're using the expression `$alert.Labels.alertname`. Only you know what it is as you posted no details regarding to it.

Comment: Because it seems old data still there after interation. So I'll get duplicate data next time.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @icza please check it again, I added more detail just now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just relealize it cannot be resolved by zero an object. Because：

1. There is no way to keep last 'resolved' host 232.20 in wechat.
2. Next time the raw data still contains 'resolved' host 232.20, so it cannot be removed by any means.
3. so the output cannot be changed, either.

Thanks.